# Custom PDF page resources with standalone.cls

Tags: pdftex, pdf, standalone

If I want to embed custom resources into the page object generated by pdfTeX, with most document classes it doesn't matter whether I do it in the preamble on the page, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfcompresslevel 0 \pdfobjcompresslevel 0
\begin{document}
\pdfpageresources{/Foo /Bar}
.
\end{document}
```

This produces a PDF file with:

```
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Contents 3 0 R
/Resources 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595.276 841.89]
/Parent 5 0 R
>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<<
/Foo /Bar
/Font << /F8 4 0 R >>
/ProcSet [ /PDF /Text ]
>>
endobj
```

However if I try to use the `standalone` documentclass instead, the custom resource is missing:

```
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Contents 3 0 R
/Resources 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 6.088 1.052]
/Parent 5 0 R
>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<<
/Font << /F8 4 0 R >>
/ProcSet [ /PDF /Text ]
>>
endobj
```

It still works if I do it in the preamble but I'm wondering what does standalone do with the page resources that results in this happening and whether I can work around it.

Comment: standalone adds a group, you would loose the resource too if you would add a group around it in article. What type of resource are you trying to add?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Let's say that I'm doing something incredibly esoteric and hardly applicable in the real world, where I'm trying to add things like images and fonts by only embedding them inside the tex source with no external files.

Comment: @mniip `\pdfpageresources` is a toks register, so you can do `\global\pdfpageresources{/Foo /Bar}`.  The value of `\pdfpageresources` only kicks in when pdfTeX is shipping out a page, so it should be harmless, but I'm not completely sure. Ulrike can probably give you a better answer regarding this subject

Comment: @mniip I'm not trying to pry, I'm interested as I'm just working on the pdf resources for latex and wonder if I missed something. The pdf reference doesn't mention arbitrary resources, and if you try to add to the standard resources like this you will probably clash with other accesses.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's pretty much it. Trying to do weird things using only tex code.